# Convert SqlDataReader to linq expression

Tags: c#, performance, linq, sqldatareader

When looking at examples on the internet on how to use `SqlDataReader` I found things like:

```
var command = new SqlCommand(  // initialize with query and connection...
var reader = command.ExecuteReader();

while(reader.Read())
{
    var foo = reader["SomeColName"];
    // etc
}
```

Can I use the following extension method:

```
public static IEnumerable<IDataReader> ToEnumerable(this IDataReader reader)
{
     while (reader.Read())            
         yield return reader;            
}
```

In order to execute queries using linq?

If I use the following extension method will it be bad? If I care about performance should I use the first implementation?

Comment: I think performance wouldn't be an issue here, its just generating a state-machine for the yield. Other than that I'd recommend exposing `IDataRecord` instead of `IDataReader` (inheritance), otherwise you'd be exposing the `Read`-method (so users can call that method and mess up the resultset).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can't see how your proposed extension would help you, as you only get an enumeration containing **the same instance of `IDataReader`** for each read row.

I'm not sure if there is any good way to combine `IDataReader` with LINQ, but you may want something like that:

```
public static IEnumerable<Dictionary<string, object>> ToEnumerable(this IDataReader reader)
{
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        Dictionary<string, object> result = new Dictionary<string, object>();
        for (int column = 0; column < reader.FieldCount; column++)
            result.Add(reader.GetName(column), reader.GetValue(column));
        yield return result;
    }
}
```

This will return a sequence of dictionaries (one dictionary per row) which map the column name to the object in that "cell".

Unfortunatly, you lose type safety and create memory overhead. The specific implementation would still depend on what you really want to achieve. Personally, I always use only the column index instead of the name.

---

That said, I think the best approach is still to use the `IDataReader` directly to create pocos and to use this pocos with LINQ:

```
IEnumerable<string> GetSomeColValue(IDataReader reader)
{
    while(reader.Read())
        yield return reader.GetString(reader.GetOrdinal("SomeColName"));
}
```

Of course this is a shortened example. In real code I would read out all data from the reader completely and close/dispose the reader instance *inside the method that called `ExecuteReader`* before returning anything.

Answer (score 18):

You just need to cast your `IEnumerable` to `IEnumerable<IDataRecord>`

```
var enumerable = reader.Cast<IDataRecord>();
var col = enumerable.Select(record => record .GetOrdinal("SomeColName"));
```

Comment: I'm curious, where is this `Cast` extension for `IDataReader` declared? `IDataReader` doesn't even declare a `GetEnumerator` method.

Comment: (Sql|Db)DataReader implement IEnumerable. And Cast<T> is an extension method defined in System.Linq.Enumerable.

Comment: Yes interesting, `SqlDataReader` implements this, too. Never used it and MSDN doesn't tell clearly if this is an enumerator for the columns of the current row or if this iterates through rows. I'll take a look at it and maybe use it in future (though msdn states that the loop is preferable, but not why).

Comment: Checked the sources, it really iterates through the rows. +1, I like it, though you need to take a little care to know *who* is closing the `DbDataReader` etc.